Why did Hungary veto the EU joint statement on Venezuela's election irregularities?
Hungary has reportedly vetoed an EU joint statement on Venezuela's election irregularities. Is there a reason that Hungary would disagree with this position?
This seems to be at odds with Viktor Orbán's stance supporting Juan Guaidó (opposition to Maduro) in 2019.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not even clear if the premise is correct. I suggest to wait for clarifications and reopen later if needed.

Somewhat more balanced coverage here: https://europeanconservative.com/articles/news/its-fake-news-hungary-didnt-veto-the-eu-statement-against-maduro/ There will be a joint communique at the next meeting apparently. Also, Fidesz MEPs condemned Maduro's election.

The State Department of Hungary has denied that it vetoed such a statement. I vote for closing down as it is a false claim.

You shouldn't answer a question and vote to close it at the same time. Either it's off-topic or it isn't.

Yeah, don't think so.  Euronews also carries the same info: A joint EU statement denouncing "irregularities" in Venezuela's presidential election was blocked by Hungary, leading Josep Borrell to publish his own.  Could very well be "alternative facts" coming out of Orban.  Or it could be a news error - I see neither as more likely one than the other.

FWTW, the statement in your source adds that "As they [Hungary's FM] wrote, they first waited for the reports from Venezuela, and then, after studying them, they joined the joint resolution of the European Union." So, this may not be as black and white as you've quoted it, i.e. Hungary may have delayed the joint communique.
